# Angular9's reactive forms & atomic design

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, atomic-design

I am implementing [atomic design](https://bradfrost.com/blog/post/atomic-web-design/) in my Angular 9 application. This means that I will build my pages with atoms, molecules & organisms. All is going fine, except for the ReactiveFormsModule.

I want to convert the `<input />` to its own component, so that I don't have to duplicate the associated HTML all the time. However, reactive forms is not having any of it.

The sample below is returns an error onload: `ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'field2'`

I made a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/JoelOnGithub/angular-atomic-design) example with the full code.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({selector: 'app-root',templateUrl: './app.component.html'})
export class AppComponent {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = fb.group({
      field1: ['value1', [Validators.required]],
      field2: ['value2', [Validators.required]],
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {console.log(this.form.value);}
}
```

**app.component.html** Here I tried replacing the second input with the atom.

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit();">
  <label>
    Field 1 <input formControlName="field1" />
  </label>

  <label>
    Field 2 <app-input formControlName="field2"></app-input>
  </label>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**input.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-input',
  template: '<input [formControlName]="formControlName" />',
})
export class InputComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() formControlName: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

I have tried to implement a `ControlValueAccessor`, through [this tutorial](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/angular-nested-reactive-forms-using-cvas-b394ba2e5d0d) but this resulted in weird behaviour.

Can anyone show me how to achieve this?

Comment: If you implement control valueaccessor are you getting any error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if u want to make ur life easy then use FormControl as input from ur custom component
this is code from my app

```
// custom component 
@Input() set control(value: FormControl) {
    if (this._control !== value) {
      this._control = value;
    }
  }
// tempalte
<input [formControl]="_control">
```

input parent control i not using formBuilder but fromControl and formGroup directly.

```
name = new FormControl('');

constructor(){
let name = this.name;
this.formGroup = new FromGroup({name });


// template
        <custom-control [control]="name">
```

## Updated solution into the samples from the question:

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({selector: 'app-root',templateUrl: './app.component.html'})
export class AppComponent {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = fb.group({
      field1: ['value1', [Validators.required]],
      field2: ['value2', [Validators.required]],
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {console.log(this.form.value);}
}
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit();">
  <label>
    Field 1 <input formControlName="field1" />
  </label>

  <label>
    Field 2 <app-input [control]="form.controls.field2"></app-input>
  </label>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**input.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-input',
  template: '<input [formControl]="formControl" />',
})
export class InputComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() set control(value: FormControl) {
    if (this.formControl !== value) {
      this.formControl = value;
    }
  }

  formControl: FormControl;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void { }
}
```

Comment: Man, you are a genius. This solved it. It also works with the formBuilder.

Comment: Yes it work with it.
but thing is to get formControl from FromGroup u have to use magic string which I don't like.
I prefer more typed code then small untyped